# Determine which block is pressed on a screen

Tags: java, android

I have drawn 36 blocks/square of size 54x54 in a specific place on a screen. (See picture below)

My question is how should I determine which block is pressed? I also want to have some sorts of ID for each block. I know the x and y coordinates of where on the screen a user have pressed. But because a block is on a certain area on the screen and I have 36 blocks this makes it difficult for me to find out which one of the block is pressed.

Here is the code on how I draw the blocks below.

```
    int x = 72;
    int y = 169;

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){

        for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
            g.drawImage(Assets.red, x, y);
            squares[i][j] = new Square(x, y, i, j);
            x += 54+2;
        }
        x = 72;
        y += 54+2;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Why cannot you go from coordinate to block -- isn't it just arithmetic (or am I missing something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to stick with just arithmetic operations as Rob mentioned.

You can refer to this [Link](http://androidforums.com/android-games/210019-touch-event-image-made-canvas.html)

or  instead of drawing you can add image view and set onclick on that.
(Since i cannot comment i have to add it as answer)